# Additive and scalable independent mathematical function

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, linear-transformations

I would like to know some functions which are independent from scaling and additive. On the other words, I am looking some functions $F$ that are not changing when a constant is added or multiplied to them.

$F(aX)=F(X)$

$F(X+k)=F(X)$

Comment: For the second, see [periodic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function) like $sin(x) = sin(x + 2\pi)$.
For the first I'm not too sure (besides constant functions). You could more or less use exponential function of base $a$, such as $a^x$ but this does not really match what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever that sum operation forms a group it will be constant, since for all $x,y$,
$$f(y) = f(y + ((-y) + x)) = f(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

The first condition can be exressed by saying the $F$ must be periodic on a semilogarithmic plot, and the second on a Cartesian plot. Both conditions are incompatible unless $F$ is constant.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. How about first conditions F(aX)=F(X) ? Are they any functions?

Comment: @MohammadAliNematollahi: hem, didn't I say "$F$ must be periodic on a semilogarithmic plot" ?

Comment: Yes I did understand but could you please give me an example?

Comment: Obviously $f(\log(x))$ where $f$ is any periodic function.